# long long int compilation error in vc++ 6.0

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors

I'm encountering this error while compiling some old VC++ 6.0 source code.

```
error C2632: 'long' followed by 'long' is illegal
```

There's a part of the code that declares a long long int variable which caused the error. Does anybody know how I can fix this error compiling it in VC++ 6.0? I've searched around and I've read that this data type is not yet supported in this version. However, this is an old code and I'm sure this was compiled in VC++ 6.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK Visual C++ 6.0 only supports `__int64` (Microsoft's own type definition for 64-bit integers). `long long` is a standard type from C99, which 6.0 doesn't support.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think VC6 supports the long long data type, but if you have the necessary typedefs already you could replace "long long" with "__int64" with a minimum of hassle.

Answer (score 0):

> error C2632: 'long' followed by 'long' is illegal

Microsoft finally added support for `long long` and `unsigned long long` at [Visual Studio 2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/06/19/c111417-features-in-vs-2015-rtm/).

Also see [Which C99 features are available in the MS Visual Studio compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9610747).

---

> Does anybody know how I can fix this error compiling it in VC++ 6.0?

The problem also exists in the early .Net compilers, too. You have to use macros and Microsoft extensions to do it in a portable manner.

Here's how [Crypto++ handles it](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/config.h#L197) (the project still supports old compilers to avoid forcing users to make unwanted choices):

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__BORLANDC__)
    typedef unsigned __int64 word64;
    #define W64LIT(x) x##ui64
#else
    typedef unsigned long long word64;
    #define W64LIT(x) x##ULL
#endif
```

You would then [use it like so](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/blake2.cpp#L60). It will work for VC++ 5.0/6.0, Visual Studio .Net, Visual Studio 2010, GCC, Clang, Intel, etc.

```
word64 x = W64LIT(0x0000000000000001);
```

Comment: They actually had `long long` since at least VS2010, not 2013.  According to the MSDN, the earliest version to have it was actually VS 2005, where it was listed as equivalent to `__int64`.  It _might_ have been in VS.NET 2003, but the archived documentation contradicts itself.  [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc953fe1(v=vs.71).aspx), chart 1 doesn't mention it, but chart 2 does.