# How to change the compiler of VS?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, c99

I'm using VS 2010. I have changed the settings for compiler C code instead of C++. It works fine, but the problem is MS compilers don't supports C99 standard,for this reason I'm looking for a C compiler that can works with VS 10. How to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What aspects of C99 do you need? AFAIK some aspects *are* implemented in the VS 2010 compilers.

Comment: Well, things like: `//`,  `for(int i = 0; .. )` and `enum { A, B } char*foo[] = { [A] = "..", [B] = "$.." };` (I have a lot of code using this). The solution is migrated for a compiler that really supports C99, once I can't change the default compiler of VS,right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS visual studio don't support c99, however they have implemented [certain features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610747/which-c99-features-are-available-in-the-ms-visual-studio-compiler) of c99.

From this [Microsoft page](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/526116/c99-support), their reply for c99 support:

***Question by a user:***

> "I would like to see C99 support available in Visual Studio. The
>   amount of work to add C99 support should pale in comparison to C++0x.
>
> As the compiler for the dominant PC platform, Microsoft should really
>   try harder to implement a standard that's over 10 years old --
>   especially because the C community is arguably larger than the C# or
>   C++ community."

***Microsoft's reply:***

> "Unfortunately 1) There are many, many more users of the Microsoft C++
>   compiler than there are of the C compiler; 2) Anytime we do customers
>   discussion and/or solicit feedback the overwhelming response is that
>   we should focus on C++ (especially at the moment C++-0x); 3) We just
>   don't have the resources to do everything we would like. So while we
>   are slowly improving our C-99 support (and we are active in the C-1x
>   discussions) I can't promise we'll add any of these features."

Comment: MSC supports all c89 but limited c99 features. So you can't do that. Otherwise, you may run into problems when you use some latest gcc (c99 or c11) features.