# How to use MonoDevelop for C coding?

Tags: c, ide, monodevelop

How to add support for C coding on windows? I have downloaded the MonoDevelop last version, but on `file > new solution` I only see: `C#`, `IL`, and `VB.NET` programming languages and I can't find it on `Tools > Add-in > Gallery > language bindings` as well. Thanks

Comment: Did this(http://monodevelop.com/documentation/creating_c_and_cpp_projects) give any insight to you?

Comment: Visual C++ Express if free to download and use. It doesn't come with everything (e.g. no MFC classes), but otherwise is a very good C (and C++) IDE.

Comment: @positron: No. As I said before, file > new solution I only see: C#, IL, and VB.NET programming languages.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I agree,is very good IDE. But the problem is the Microsoft's compilers that did not support C99 std.I have tried it, check out my question that I have created yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710791/how-to-change-the-compiler-of-vs

Comment: Which version did you install? It seems the C/C++ is supported from v1.0 (http://monodevelop.com/download/monodevelop_1.0_released)

Comment: Not sure about Win environment, but for Unix QtCreator seems to be very good. And since Qt is working under Windows too, QtCreator should work there too.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, C is not supported in the windows version. Look at the [Feature List](http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Feature_List)