# Compiling a file with TCC on windows with a library from C99

Tags: c, compilation, libraries, c99, tcc

So the latest version of TCC supposedly has some of the features of C99 implemented, however, I have found that it does not include C99's Math library.

Is there a way I can get it to use more of C99's libraries on windows? I googled around and found some advice mostly pertaining to Linux, but for this project I need to get it to work on windows.

EDIT: This is not a question about getting 'any' compiler on the windows platform. I realize that there are many compilers. I specifically need to get TCC to do this.

EDIT: The project needs to do some on the fly C compilation, and we would like to see if we can use TCC for this feature.

Comment: Be specific, what is missing??

Comment: Why do you use TCC for a large project? Its optimizer are not good and most probably used for small scale purpose. GCC and Clang have rather good C99 support

Comment: The project needs to do some on the fly C compilation, and we would like to see if we can use TCC for this feature

Comment: According to TCC website, nothing much in C99 are supported thought

Comment: yeah, that's why I was asking if anyone had experience integrating their own packages into the compiler. I know on linux some guy from a previous question was able to compile tcc himself adding in some of his own libs from /usr/lib/. I would like to know if anyone had done anything similar in windows

Comment: you also have a option of using Eclipse IDE for C with gcc

Comment: @Vagish the IDE doesn't relate anything here. For example he wants to embed the compiler into his program then inherently there's no usage  of IDE, and he can't embed a whole IDE though

Comment: @Luu As I have mentioned n my comment to use gcc compiler and Eclipse IDE as an option to TCC,there are other options also.But as I am not from CS domain,please explain me what timsbleung is trying to achieve and what do you mean by embedding a compiler into program.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for Windows indicates that [the TCC installation on Windows deploys a minimal set of MinGW headers](http://repo.or.cz/w/tinycc.git/blob/refs/heads/mob:/win32/tcc-win32.txt#l78). Copy the headers you need from MinGW into the `tcc/include/winapi` (i.e. place them under `tcc-build-root/win32/include/winapi`) and then build tcc with `build-tcc.bat`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Visual Studio Express Edition for 'C'.It's free and IDE is more developed than TCC

Comment: Hehe, no, not for C99 :)

Comment: @Hans Why not?VS C++ 2013 supports C99

Comment: @Vagish no, not complete. ["Visual C++ 2013 implements support for most of C99 by utilizing libraries from Dinkumware."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#Implementations). VC is a C++ compiler and it never aims for fully C99 support http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293.aspx

Comment: "Microsoft has made it clear that they see no strong push from the market to allocate resources to support C99 in MSVC, so it's almost certain that the only parts of C99 you'll see in MSVC's C compiler mode are those that get brought in because of C++." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610747/which-c99-features-are-available-in-the-ms-visual-studio-compiler?rq=1

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc That second quote is from 2012. VS2013 does add *many* C99 features that previous versions of the VC compiler lacked.

Comment: The OP's reason for using TCC is unspecifid. It may not be *just* because he wants a C99 compiler. If that were the case, MinGW would probably be the simplest suggestion, as it certainly supports all of C99.

Comment: @DavidMertens The reason was buried in a comment; I copied it to the question description for convenience.

Comment: The reasons to use TCC would generally not be because of its support for the standard...but because it is small (~150K) and open source.  It could be used to embed a C compiler into another program and not carry a lot of dependencies.  For listed reasons, MS is a poor choice for standards compliance (just in general as they are pragmatic) and the compiler is not open source...and a lot larger than 150K.