# List of MSVC features with the respective version?

Tags: c, visual-c++

I am trying to find a list of `MSVC` features with the respective version they appeared in so I could do something like this:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER > X
#define MY_INLINE __forceinline
#else
#define MY_INLINE inline
#endif
```

With `gcc` for example, there is a list of the [minimum version for all attributes](https://ohse.de/uwe/articles/gcc-attributes.html). Is there something similar for `MSVC`?

Comment: [This might be closer to what you're looking for although for C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9610747/7076153

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This article describes all the breaking changes from **Visual Studio 2015** going back to **Visual Studio 2003**, and in this article the terms "new behavior" or "now" refer to Visual Studio 2015 and later. The terms "old behavior" and "before" refer to Visual Studio 2013 and earlier releases:

- [Visual C++ Change History](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/visual-cpp-change-history-2003-2015)

---

This article describes C++11/14/17 features in Visual C++:

- [C++ 11/14/17 Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx)

---

The following table presents compiler support for new C++ features:

- [C++ Compiler Support](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)

---

Here are some other references that I found:

- [Major Changes in Visual C++4.1 and 4.2](http://web.archive.org/web/20100228175137/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697418(VS.71).aspx)
- [Major Changes in Visual C++ 5.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979)
- [Major Changes in Visual C++ 6.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979)
- [C++11/14 Core Language Features in VS 2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2013/12/02/c1114-core-language-features-in-vs-2013-and-the-nov-2013-ctp/)
- [C++11/14 Feature Tables For Visual Studio 14](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/06/11/c1114-feature-tables-for-visual-studio-14-ctp1/)
- [C++11/14/17 Features In VS 2015 Preview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/11/17/c111417-features-in-vs-2015-preview/)
- [C++17 Progress in VS 2017 15.5 and 15.6](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/12/19/c17-progress-in-vs-2017-15-5-and-15-6/)

---

This link summarizes the ISO C++03, C++11, C++14, C++17, and Draft C++20 language standards conformance of compiler features and Standard Library features for the C++ compiler in Visual Studio 2017 and earlier versions:

- [Visual C++ Language Conformance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance)

---

Here is the information about using [Internal Version Numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B) of MSVC:

> The predefined macro _MSC_VER indicates the major and minor version
>   numbers of the Visual C++ compiler. The macro's value is an integer
>   literal in which the last two digits indicate the minor version number
>   and the preceding digits indicate the major version number.
>
> From Visual Studio 2017, _MSC_VER is incremented monotonically at
>   every Visual C++ toolset update. Thus, for example, the version of
>   MSVC++ 14.1 that ships with Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3.0 sets
>   _MSC_VER to 1911. Microsoft recommends using the >= operator to test the value of _MSC_VER.

Here are values of _MSC_VER for various versions of the Visual C++ compiler:

```
MSC    1.0   _MSC_VER == 100
MSC    2.0   _MSC_VER == 200
MSC    3.0   _MSC_VER == 300
MSC    4.0   _MSC_VER == 400
MSC    5.0   _MSC_VER == 500
MSC    6.0   _MSC_VER == 600
MSC    7.0   _MSC_VER == 700
MSVC++ 1.0   _MSC_VER == 800
MSVC++ 2.0   _MSC_VER == 900
MSVC++ 4.0   _MSC_VER == 1000 (Developer Studio 4.0)
MSVC++ 4.2   _MSC_VER == 1020 (Developer Studio 4.2)
MSVC++ 5.0   _MSC_VER == 1100 (Visual Studio 97 version 5.0)
MSVC++ 6.0   _MSC_VER == 1200 (Visual Studio 6.0 version 6.0)
MSVC++ 7.0   _MSC_VER == 1300 (Visual Studio .NET 2002 version 7.0)
MSVC++ 7.1   _MSC_VER == 1310 (Visual Studio .NET 2003 version 7.1)
MSVC++ 8.0   _MSC_VER == 1400 (Visual Studio 2005 version 8.0)
MSVC++ 9.0   _MSC_VER == 1500 (Visual Studio 2008 version 9.0)
MSVC++ 10.0  _MSC_VER == 1600 (Visual Studio 2010 version 10.0)
MSVC++ 11.0  _MSC_VER == 1700 (Visual Studio 2012 version 11.0)
MSVC++ 12.0  _MSC_VER == 1800 (Visual Studio 2013 version 12.0)
MSVC++ 14.0  _MSC_VER == 1900 (Visual Studio 2015 version 14.0)
MSVC++ 14.1  _MSC_VER == 1910 (Visual Studio 2017 version 15.0)
MSVC++ 14.11 _MSC_VER == 1911 (Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3)
MSVC++ 14.12 _MSC_VER == 1912 (Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5)
MSVC++ 14.13 _MSC_VER == 1913 (Visual Studio 2017 version 15.6)
MSVC++ 14.14 _MSC_VER == 1914 (Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7)
```