# Why to use `SEH` and how to use it properly?

Tags: c++, com, atl, shell-extensions, seh

I'm learning Shell Extensions from an old but nevertheless outstanding "The Complete Idiot's Guide" series of articles by Michael Dunn. The [second part](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/445/The-Complete-Idiots-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Exten-2) describes an extension that allows to register and unregister `COM Servers` via context menu. There's a `CProgressDlg` class which is responsible for iterating through the list of dlls that implement the required procedures, trying to load them, call the required procedure, save the operation result as a message to be later shown to the user. Following is the excerpt from the code:

```
typedef std::list< std::basic_string<TCHAR> > string_list;

class CProgressDlg : public CDialogImpl<CProgressDlg>
{
    protected:
        bool         m_bStopSign;
        HWND         m_hwndList;
        const string_list* m_pFileList;
        string_list  m_lsStatusMessages;    // list of status messages for the dialog
        const CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO* m_pCmdInfo;
    
        void DoWork();
}
void CProgressDlg::DoWork()
{
    USES_CONVERSION;
    HRESULT(STDAPICALLTYPE * pfn)();
    HINSTANCE hinst;
    TCHAR     szMsg[512];
    LPCSTR    pszFnName;
    WORD      wCmd;
    LVITEM    rItem;
    int       nIndex = 0;
    bool      bSuccess;

    // work area - this used to be outside DoWork() so we could use try/finally in that function.
    std::basic_string<TCHAR> strMsg;

    wCmd = LOWORD(m_pCmdInfo->lpVerb);

    // We only support 2 commands, so check the value passed in lpVerb.
    if (0 != wCmd && 1 != wCmd)
    {
        ATLASSERT(0);   // should never get here
        return;
    }

    // Determine which function we'll be calling.  Note that these strings are
    // not enclosed in the _T macro, since GetProcAddress() only takes an
    // ANSI string for the function name.
    pszFnName = wCmd ? "DllUnregisterServer" : "DllRegisterServer";

    for (string_list::const_iterator it = m_pFileList->begin();
        it != m_pFileList->end(); it++)
    {
        bSuccess = false;
        hinst = NULL;
        *szMsg = '\0';

        // We will print a status message into szMsg, which will eventually
        // be stored in the LPARAM of a listview control item.
        __try
        {
            // Try to load the next file.
            hinst = LoadLibraryEx(it->c_str(), NULL, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH);

            // If it failed, construct a friendly error message.
            if (NULL == hinst)
            {
                void* pvMsgBuf = NULL;
                DWORD dwLastErr = GetLastError();

                FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
                    FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                    NULL, dwLastErr,
                    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
                    (LPTSTR)&pvMsgBuf, 0, NULL);

                wsprintf(szMsg, _T("LoadLibraryEx failed on this module.\nError 0x%08lX (%s)"),
                    dwLastErr, pvMsgBuf ? pvMsgBuf : _T("No description available"));

                LocalFree(pvMsgBuf);
                continue;
            }

            // Get the address of the register/unregister function.
            (FARPROC&)pfn = GetProcAddress(hinst, pszFnName);

            // If it wasn't found, construct an error message.
            if (NULL == pfn)
            {
                wsprintf(szMsg, _T("%hs not found in this module."), pszFnName);
                continue;
            }

            // Call the function!
            HRESULT hr = pfn();

            // Construct a message listing the result of the function call.
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                bSuccess = true;
                wsprintf(szMsg, _T("%hs succeeded on %s"), pszFnName, it->c_str());
            }
            else
            {
                void* pvMsgBuf = NULL;

                FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
                    FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                    NULL, hr,
                    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
                    (LPTSTR)&pvMsgBuf, 0, NULL);

                wsprintf(szMsg, _T("%hs failed on %s\nError 0x%08lX: %s"),
                    pszFnName, it->c_str(), (DWORD)hr,
                    NULL != pvMsgBuf ? pvMsgBuf : _T("(No description available)"));

                LocalFree(pvMsgBuf);
            }
        }   // end __try
        __finally
        {
            // Fill in the LVITEM struct.  The item text will be the filename,
            // and the LPARAM will point to a copy of the szMsg status message.
            strMsg = szMsg;
            m_lsStatusMessages.push_back(strMsg);

            ZeroMemory(&rItem, sizeof(LVITEM));
            rItem.mask = LVIF_PARAM | LVIF_TEXT;
            rItem.iItem = nIndex;
            rItem.pszText = const_cast<LPTSTR>(it->c_str());
            rItem.lParam = (LPARAM)(DWORD_PTR)m_lsStatusMessages.back().c_str();

            ListView_InsertItem(m_hwndList, &rItem);

            // Set the text in column 2 to "succeeded" or "failed" depending 
            // on the outcome of the function call.
            ListView_SetItemText(m_hwndList, nIndex++, 1,
                bSuccess ? _T("Succeeded") : _T("Failed"));

            if (NULL != hinst)
                FreeLibrary(hinst);
        }

        // Process messages in our queue - this is much easier than doing it
        // "the real way" with a worker thread. This is how we detect a click
        // on the Stop button.
        MSG  msg;

        while (PeekMessage(&msg, m_hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        // Resize the list columns.
        ListView_SetColumnWidth(m_hwndList, 0, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER);
        ListView_SetColumnWidth(m_hwndList, 1, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER);
    }   // end for
}
```

I want to understand why did he decide to use `SEH` in the first place, why couldn't he use the regular `try/catch`? He even moved the `strMsg` out of the method to the global space which by itself is as far is I understood previously is better to be avoided. But still the project could only be compiled with the exception handing `/EHa` option, I can speculate that this's because of the `it` variable which is used in the `for` loop, but I'm not sure that my assumption is correct and why would a list iteration variable need to be destructured, isn't it a kind of a pointer to the current list item?
How this function could be possibly rewritten in order to get things done in an acceptable way? I've read about `RAII` wrappers and that in order to get functions that use `SEH` alongside with objects that require unwinding compilable without changing the aforementioned exception handing option these two have to be separated into different functions, but I just can't wrap my head around all that, and some help will be much appreciated.

---

## Update

In order to make the objects unwinding possible I took the `SEH` exceptions handling out from the loop into a different method.

```
void CProgressDlg::ProcessLib(LPCWSTR lpLibFileName, LPCSTR pszFnName)
{
    bool      bSuccess;
    HINSTANCE hinst;
    TCHAR     szMsg[512];
    HRESULT(STDAPICALLTYPE * pfn)();
    LVITEM    rItem;
    int       nIndex = 0;

    bSuccess = false;
    hinst = NULL;
    *szMsg = '\0';

    // We will print a status message into szMsg, which will eventually
    // be stored in the LPARAM of a listview control item.
    __try
    {
        // Try to load the next file.
        hinst = LoadLibraryEx(lpLibFileName, NULL, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH);

        // If it failed, construct a friendly error message.
        if (NULL == hinst)
        {
            void* pvMsgBuf = NULL;
            DWORD dwLastErr = GetLastError();

            FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
                FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                NULL, dwLastErr,
                MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
                (LPTSTR)&pvMsgBuf, 0, NULL);

            wsprintf(szMsg, _T("LoadLibraryEx failed on this module.\nError 0x%08lX (%s)"),
                dwLastErr, pvMsgBuf ? pvMsgBuf : _T("No description available"));

            LocalFree(pvMsgBuf);
            return;
        }

        // Get the address of the register/unregister function.
        (FARPROC&)pfn = GetProcAddress(hinst, pszFnName);

        // If it wasn't found, construct an error message.
        if (NULL == pfn)
        {
            wsprintf(szMsg, _T("%hs not found in this module."), pszFnName);
            return;
        }

        // Call the function!
        HRESULT hr = pfn();

        // Construct a message listing the result of the function call.
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            bSuccess = true;
            wsprintf(szMsg, _T("%hs succeeded on %s"), pszFnName, lpLibFileName);
        }
        else
        {
            void* pvMsgBuf = NULL;

            FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
                FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                NULL, hr,
                MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
                (LPTSTR)&pvMsgBuf, 0, NULL);

            wsprintf(szMsg, _T("%hs failed on %s\nError 0x%08lX: %s"),
                pszFnName, lpLibFileName, (DWORD)hr,
                NULL != pvMsgBuf ? pvMsgBuf : _T("(No description available)"));

            LocalFree(pvMsgBuf);
        }
    }   // end __try
    __finally
    {
        // Fill in the LVITEM struct.  The item text will be the filename,
        // and the LPARAM will point to a copy of the szMsg status message.
        //strMsg = szMsg;
        m_lsStatusMessages.push_back(szMsg); // <-- This line gives C2712   Cannot use __try in functions that require object unwinding


        ZeroMemory(&rItem, sizeof(LVITEM));
        rItem.mask = LVIF_PARAM | LVIF_TEXT;
        rItem.iItem = nIndex;
        rItem.pszText = const_cast<LPTSTR>(lpLibFileName);
        rItem.lParam = (LPARAM)(DWORD_PTR)m_lsStatusMessages.back().c_str();

        ListView_InsertItem(m_hwndList, &rItem);

        // Set the text in column 2 to "succeeded" or "failed" depending 
        // on the outcome of the function call.
        ListView_SetItemText(m_hwndList, nIndex++, 1,
            bSuccess ? _T("Succeeded") : _T("Failed"));

        if (NULL != hinst)
            FreeLibrary(hinst);
    }
}
```

But now a `push_back` to the list of strings, which is part of the class gives me the `C2712` error. Why modification of an object that exists outside of the scope of function that requires object unwinding gives me this error?

Comment: _"The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions - Part II - __15 May 2006__"_ - this might pre-date regular `try/catch` (or it's full implementation in MSVC) would need to check the Standards and MS docs.

Comment: SEH are considered obsolete. Even Microsoft acknowledges this now (see "C++ exceptions versus Windows SEH exceptions" in  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/errors-and-exception-handling-modern-cpp )

Comment: @CowCorporation "*Obsolete*" is too strong of a word. From the linked page [Structured Exception Handling (C/C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=msvc-160): "*we recommend that you use ISO-standard C++ exception handling. It makes your code more portable and flexible*. ***However***, *to maintain existing code or for particular kinds of programs, you still might have to use SEH*".

Comment: In this context (Windows Shell API calls), you don't need `try` nor `__try`. Just check the error codes: HRESULT for API that return HRESULT, GetLastError for API that use SetLastError, etc.

Comment: @RichardCritten I've checked it and the very first standardized C++ iso/iec 14882:1998 (C++98) already had exception handling(page 291) with `try/catch`. [VS 2003 Tech Docs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979), thanks [@Abhishek-Keshri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49990327/1707245), on page 23183 states that `The Microsoft C++ compiler
implements the C++ exception handling model based on the ANSI C++ standard` and already at the time they recommended `For C++ programs, it is
recommended that you use the C++ exception-handling mechanism`(@CowCorporation).

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for your input, could you please add several words on when would I need to use SEH?

Comment: You can use SEH when you call a code that's not yours and want to protect against "exceptional code situations" (ie: pointer reference bugs mostly) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp. I personally almost never use it.

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, I've read it, and that's exactly what happens inside this method - the extension calls someone else's code from an arbitrary library that user selects, and I think that it's a good idea to protect against bugs or memory issues in that code, since these could lead to explorer crash.

Comment: If you already know all this, what's your question then?

Comment: @SimonMourier I don't claim knowledge, these are my assumptions based on what I read before posting this question, and I'm asking for clarifications, that's all. You told that in context of this question one don't need neither `try` nor `__try`, but then you told that I can use `SEH` when I call code that's not mine, but that's exactly what happens inside this function in question, so why do you think that exception handling is not necessary here?

Comment: If you compile with /EHa then try/catch(...) will catch-em-all, including the nasty SEH exceptions.  Dereference a null pointer or divide by zero to see that for yourself.   That `catch(...)` gets so powerful is not exactly a grand feature, but right now you like it.